# Styling two instances of fancybox-close on the same page with possible use of wrapCSS attribute

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, styling, fancybox-2

I have two fancyboxes on the same page, and I would like to have a different style/position of the `fancybox-close` button for one of them.

It was recommended for me to use the `wrapCSS` API option, however, I don't know how to use it and I haven't found any detailed documentation of how it works. I've seen a few people talk about it here on stackoverflow, but not in enough detail that I could glean how to use it (e.g. [Custom styles for multiple instances of Fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655112/custom-styles-for-multiple-instances-of-fancybox) among others).

Therefore my question is:

Is it the `wrapCSS` option a viable route for adding additional style to the `fancybox-close` selector? and how do I use it?  (a reference/link to good documentation on this would be a perfectly acceptable answer)

Is there any other viable option?

I would love to see some code examples when applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I wouldn't use the `wrapCSS` option but adding an extra *class* to those elements I want with a different style, i.e.

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">Fancybox-close button is on the right</a>

<a class="fancybox closeLeft" rel="gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg">Fancybox-close button is on the left</a>
```

**Notice** that the second link has the class `closeLeft`, which tells me the fancybox *close button* will positioned on the `left` rather than the default position (`right`)

Then I would use the `afterShow` callback to validate the *class* and change the style accordingly :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow: function () {
        if ($(this.element).is(".closeLeft")) {
            // change styles for this element
            $(".fancybox-close").css({
                left: -18,
                right: "auto"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E3Zut/)**