# Remove Scroll from Specific Fancy Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have 3 fancy box popups on single page.

I have applied this CSS property on fancybox because I needed a vertical scrollbar for 2 popups:

```
.fancybox-inner{ overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden !important; }
```

Now I m adding 3rd Popup, but i dont need Vertical scrollbar in it.(No scrollbar).

**Here is my Fancybox script:**

```
$(".container").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    helpers : { title : { type : 'over' } }
   });
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: you can add an extra class to it using the option `wrapCss: 'newClass';`.  Just target the 3rd popup with a different selector - [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655112/custom-styles-for-multiple-instances-of-fancybox)

Comment: Will i define newClass in css ?

Comment: so you can use the new class like this: `.newClass .fancybox-inner{ other styles here }`

Comment: Answer accpted. It worked. Thanks alot mate :)